# What is the meaning of 'spike protein' in this context

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

So that is the headline on NY Times:

'Is the future just a spike protein stamping on a human face, Forever?'

A link to the matter: 'https://www.nytimes.com/2021/08/05/opinion/covid-delta-vaccinated-flu.html'

All I can think of is: 'spike protein' is used to mean a Mask. but looking up definition of: 'spike protein' i fail to see a conection

Answer (score 3):

"[Spike protein](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peplomer)" a structure on a virus that it uses to enter and infect human cells.  Coronavirus is covered in spike proteins.

The metaphor "stamping on a human face" gives the image of a dystopian future in which humans are oppressed. It is a particular reference to a quote by the English author George Orwell:

> If you want a vision of the future, imagine a boot stamping on a human face - forever. (*1984*)

So the author wonders if the future is "Humans living under oppression caused by coronavirus."

Comment: As a native English speaker who has also even read Orwell's 1984 (some time ago), I still did not actually get this reference and had a hard time parsing this headline myself (somebody was trying to be too clever, methinks).  Thanks for the pointer to that!

Answer (score 1):

A picture makes it very clear: the protein contains a form that looks like a spike.

The picture comes from here: [news-medical net](https://www.news-medical.net/health/What-are-Spike-Proteins.aspx)
[image: spike protein]

Spike = from Merriam Webster:

Definition of spike (Entry 1 of 3)
1: a very large nail
2a: one of a row of pointed irons placed (as on the top of a wall) to prevent passage
b(1): one of several metal projections set in the sole and heel of a shoe to improve traction
(2)spikes plural : a pair of shoes having spikes attached to the soles or soles and heels

[ETC]

“Spike.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, [spike](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spike.%20Accessed%205%20Aug.%202021).

Answer (score 0):

Covid-19 has been big news for the past 18 months and many terms that would normally only have been heard within the scientific community are now in everyday speech.

The Covid-19 virus is described as having 'spike proteins' - these can be visibly seen if you look at a depiction of the virus. These spikes are apparently how it attaches to the cells it attacks and part of the reason it is so virulent. The spikes have also been deemed as its weakness, and most of the vaccines work by creating immunity to the spike proteins rather than the virus itself. Many vaccines for other viruses contain 'dead' or 'deactivated' virus cells in order to create immunity, but most Covid vaccines contain either synthetic cells with the spike protein, or some other virus that doesn't attack humans but has the same spikes.

So, the headline is metaphorical - it is really asking whether humans will continue to be attacked by these kind of viruses as they mutate and adapt.